# Соответствие списков условию непрерывного возрастания

Tags: python, циклы, if

Даны два целочисленных списка A и B, необходимо проверить, что они упорядочены по возрастанию и непрерывно возрастают, если это не так, выдать сообщение о несоответствии.
100% есть гораздо более тривиальные и логичные способы решения этой задачки, но просьба подсказать, почему в моём коде некорректно работает проверка на соответствие.
Для последовательностей **a =1 2 3** и **b = 4 5 6** и **a= 1 1 1** и **b= 2 2 2** все работает корректно, а например для **a = 1 1 2** и **b = 2 3 4** срабатывает некорректно. Я исходил из логики создания новых списков с добавление разниц из предыдущих. Новые списки отражаются корректно, а вот сравнения минимумов нет.
Код:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
c = []
d = []
try:
    for i in range(len(a)):
        m = a[i + 1] - a[i]
        c.append(m)
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    for j in range(len(b)):
        k = b[j + 1] - b[j]
        d.append(k)
except IndexError:
    pass
if min(c) <= 0:
    if min(d) <= 0:
        print('lists dont meet with the requirements')
    else:
        print('Ok')
```

Comment: "_срабатывает некорректно_" это как?

Comment: Не дописал, извиняюсь, список должен непрерывно возрастать

Comment: почему два списка? какая между ними связь? почему минимумы? не понятно.

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чем все таки проблема? Выводит не то, что вы ожидали увидеть? И зачем цикл помещать в `try`? Можете просто цикл до `len(a) - 1` сделать.

Comment: Да, вывод не тот, который ожидаю. Например, список **1 1 2** не возрастает непрерывно, соответственно должно выдавать сообщение про requirements. Про `len(a) - 1` большое спасибо, что подсказали, без `try` выдавал IndexError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял при `a = 1 1 2` и `b = 2 3 4` вы ожидали увидеть `lists dont meet with the requirements`, но получаете `Ok`.

Дело все в последних проверках. Если `min(c) <= 0`, то вместо того, чтобы сразу сказать, что последовательность не возрастающая, вы проверяете `min(d) <= 0`, а вот `b` уже является возрастающей последовательностью и вы выводите `Ok`.

Так же, как я и писал в комментариях вы можете убрать `try` и просто сделать цикл до `len(a) - 1`.

Вот пример кода:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
c = []
d = []

for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    c.append(a[i + 1] - a[i])

for j in range(len(b) - 1):
    d.append(b[j + 1] - b[j])

if(min(c) <= 0 or min(d) <= 0):
    print('lists dont meet with the requirements')
else:
    print('Ok')
```

Если я вас не правильно понял, то отпишитесь в комментариях к ответу.

Comment: Все, теперь понятно. Спасибо, что объяснили

Answer (score 0):

Проверить на упорядоченность по возрастанию:

```py
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))

for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i] >= a[i+1]:
        print('A list don\'t meet with the requirements')
        break

for i in range(len(b)-1):
    if b[i] >= b[i+1]:
        print('B list don\'t meet with the requirements')
        break
```

Или можно обернуть все в функцию:

```py
def check(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] >= lst[i+1]:
            return False
    return True

a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
if not check(a):
    print('A list don\'t meet with the requirements')
if not check(b):
    print('B list don\'t meet with the requirements')
```

Comment: Автор понимает, что "_100% есть гораздо более тривиальные и логичные способы решения этой задачки_", но ему нужно "_подсказать, почему в моём коде некорректно работает проверка на соответствие_"